# Printing an AST to show indentation

Tags: haskell, parsec

I would like to print an Abstract Syntax Tree in Haskell. Currently I can print the tree out line by line but what I would prefer is to indent it out for each block the parsed code is within.

**E.g.**

**Code to parse:**

```
module test
foo(x,y):
    foo x y
    x + y
```

Here are my functions to create and print the AST.

**Returns the tree.**

```
parse :: String -> Either ParseError [Expr]
parse = runParser (many expr <* eof) () "[input]" . indentConfig
```

**Prints the tree.**

```
printTree :: String -> IO ()
printTree line = do
    let res = parse line
    case res of
        Left err -> print err
        Right ex -> mapM_ print ex
```

**Current output:**

```
Function "foo" ["x","y"] (FunctionCall "foo" [Variable "x",Variable "y"])
BinOp Plus (FunctionCall "x" []) (FunctionCall "y" [])
```

**Desired output:**

```
Function "foo" ["x","y"] 
    (FunctionCall "foo" [Variable "x",Variable "y"])
    BinOp Plus (FunctionCall "x" []) (FunctionCall "y" [])
```

What is the best method of achieving this?

Comment: I'm very confused. There's no plus sign in your first example, yet there's a `BinOp Plus` in the last. The first only differs in indentation, and the last differs significantly and also seems like it might be missing some parentheses. Are the two examples related in any way?

Comment: Sorry I wrote that in a confusing way. I've just updated the question.

Comment: Do you simply want it to be indented in some uniform way, or do you want the indentation to match the indentation of the input? If the former, I believe @LeventErkok's answer is correct. The latter is a bit more complicated.

Comment: I would like the indentation to match how many places to the right the element is in the tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several packages on Hackage that lets you show such tree structures in an "indented" way. Previously, I used Iavor Diatchki's `pretty-show` package, and it does a really good job. You might want to give that a try:  https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pretty-show

Comment: Hi Levent, thank you for the reply. Although I could use a library is there not a simple method of achieving something like this in a functional language? If mutable variables were possible it would be a matter of storing the places traversed to the right and adding it as indentation. I understand I might be asking for something more difficult then it sounds.

Comment: Hi Michael.. Well, somebody has to write the code. You can surely do it, but efficient and "pretty" printing is a surprisingly tricky topic. (Google search will find you lots of papers on the topic, and hackage has many packages.) The advantage of `pretty-show` is that it's easy to use and does all the heavy lifting for you. You can even "convince" ghci to use it as you play with the command line. See here: http://teh.id.au/posts/2017/02/13/interactive-print/index.html

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for the doc it looks interesting. I'll give pretty-show a try. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own `prettyPrint` function which takes in the AST and the level of indentation and then recursively prints the nodes in the AST, incrementing the indentation level as necessary.

In this function you will need to specifically handle the AST nodes that increase the indentation levels.

Here is an example of such a function.

```
data AST =
    Function String [String] [AST]
  | BinOp AST AST AST
  | Plus
  | FunctionCall String [AST]
  | Variable String
  deriving (Show)

prettyPrint :: Int -> AST -> String
prettyPrint n (Function a b c) = "Function " ++ show a ++ " " ++ show b ++
    foldl (++) "" (map (\x -> "\n" ++ take (n + 1) (repeat '\t') ++
    prettyPrint (n + 1) x) c)
prettyPrint n a = show a
```

Note that there is probably a much cleaner way to write this function, but this version shows the idea in action.

If we run this on the example AST you gave, we get the following.

```
λ ~ let a = (Function "foo" ["x","y"] [FunctionCall "foo" [Variable "x",Variable "y"], BinOp Plus (FunctionCall "x" []) (FunctionCall "y" [])])
λ ~ putStrLn (prettyPrint 0 a)
Function "foo" ["x","y"]
    FunctionCall "foo" [Variable "x",Variable "y"]
    BinOp Plus (FunctionCall "x" []) (FunctionCall "y" [])
```

This also works with multiple levels of indentation.

```
λ ~ let b = (Function "foo" ["x","y"] [FunctionCall "foo" [Variable "x",Variable "y"], BinOp Plus (FunctionCall "x" []) (FunctionCall "y" []), Function "bar" ["x"] [BinOp Plus (FunctionCall "x" []) (FunctionCall "y" [])]])
b :: AST
λ ~ putStrLn (prettyPrint 0 b)
Function "foo" ["x","y"]
    FunctionCall "foo" [Variable "x",Variable "y"]
    BinOp Plus (FunctionCall "x" []) (FunctionCall "y" [])
    Function "bar" ["x"]
        BinOp Plus (FunctionCall "x" []) (FunctionCall "y" [])
```

Note, that this is only if you want to implement the functionality yourself. It is probably a much better move in the long run to use a pretty printing library that handles this for you.